# Radio Buttons Android

Tags: android, radio-button

I created an activity that , case of the radiobutton selected , sends an information to the database .
Everything is right , no error , but when i compile and click the button the application crashes . can't find the problem . This is my code

```
public class Mlo extends Activity {
private RadioButton vincinq, cinq;
private EditText num;
private RadioGroup tupe;


HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpClient httpclient ;
private void createDialog(String title, String text)
{
    // Création d'une popup affichant un message
    AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null).setTitle(title).setMessage(text)
            .create();
    ad.show();

}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mlo);
    vincinq = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.conv1);
    cinq = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.conv2);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tupe = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    // Définition du listener du bouton
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String nb = num.getText().toString();


 if (vincinq.isChecked()) {
    final String type ="25";
        final String nbnum = num.getText().toString();
        try {
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://forma-fun.comli.com/cheq.php");
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numcompte", nbnum));
         postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type));

         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));                   
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());

         createDialog("Merci ", "Votre demande a été effectuée");
         Intent i = new Intent(Mlo.this,VotreCompte.class);
         startActivity(i);
        }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
             } 
 }
 else 
     if (cinq.isChecked()){ 
         final String type1 ="50";
            final String nbnum = num.getText().toString();
            try {
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost = new HttpPost("http://forma-fun.comli.com/cheq.php");
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numcompte", nbnum));
             postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type1));

             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));                   
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());

             createDialog("Merci ", "Votre demande a été effectuée");
             Intent i = new Intent(Mlo.this,VotreCompte.class);
             startActivity(i);
            }
                 catch(Exception e)
                 {
                     Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
                 }
 }




        }

    });

  }
}
```

Logcat

```
03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at    

com.example.attijaribank2.Mlo$1.onClick(Mlo.java:56)
03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at   
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at   

android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at   

android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at   
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)

03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at    
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-13 12:13:05.282: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  
Method)
```

Comment: Any `logcat` to show ?

Comment: Do you see a NetworkOnMainThreadException? You will if you run this on HoneyComb or later...

Comment: You should not do HTTP calls in the main thread, they will give you ANR exception

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException . and I did HTTP calls on other activitys works fine.
I updated my question.

Comment: if you have a slow connection, it will give you ANR (if the call blocks for 5 secs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to instantiate `num` which throws the NullPointerException whenever you try to reference it:

```
final String nb = num.getText().toString();
```

In `onCreate()` (or any time before you try to access `num`) you need to use:

```
num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.xxx);
```

Comment: that was it !  I didn't look hard enough for something missing , my bad . Thank you !

Comment: The LogCat is one of your best tools, it tells you the exception and the line it occurred on: `java.lang.NullPointerException ... at com.example.attijaribank2.Mlo$1.onClick(Mlo.java:56)` Line 56 will lead you right to it. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should not have any network communication done on the main thread. You have to implement asyncronous calls. To implement such asyncronous calls you must extend the AsyncTask class. Maybe you can start with something like this:

```
private class HttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params;

    public void setParams(ArrayList<NameValuePair> params){
        this.params = params;
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        int count = requestStrings.length;
        String result = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://forma-fun.comli.com/cheq.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));                   
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());

            InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(content));
            String s = "";
            while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                result += s;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
// TODO You are on the GUI thread, and the first element in 
// the progress parameter contains the last progress
// published from doInBackground, so update your GUI
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(int result) {
// Processing is complete, result contains the result string 
    }
}
```

And then you can modify your onClick listener like this:

```
// Définition du listener du bouton
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{

    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String nb = num.getText().toString();


        if (vincinq.isChecked()) {
            final String type ="25";
            final String nbnum = num.getText().toString();
            try {
                HttpTask task = new HttpTask();
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numcompte", nbnum));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type1));
                task.setParams(postParameters);
                task.execute("http://forma-fun.comli.com/cheq.php");

                createDialog("Merci ", "Votre demande a été effectuée");
                Intent i = new Intent(Mlo.this,VotreCompte.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
            } 
        }
    }
}
```